# Proving that a sphere is a closed set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I have to prove that a sphere centered at $x_0$ with radius $r$

$S(x_0,r) = \{x \in X | d(x,x_0) = r\}$

is a closed set.

I know I should prove that the complement is open. If I take a point $y$ inside the complement and consider the open ball with radius $\epsilon = \frac{d-r}{2}$ where $d$ is the distance from $x_0$ to $y$ I have to show that the distance $d(x_0,y) > r$. This is where I am stuck. I thought about using the triangle inequality, but I am sure how to proceed. Any help would be greatly appreicated.

Comment: You have to specify who is $X$ and its topology. Sometimes spheres are not closed.

Comment: @SphericalTriangle, no, that's wrong. Sphere defined as above is always closed.

Comment: You can view it as a preimage of a point under a continuous map. Then there is nothing to prove really.

Comment: @lanskey If the map is continuous. In particular if the topology is given by that metric.

Comment: Of course the topology is given by metric here. The question would be absolute nonsense otherwise.

Comment: @xyxxyz: the sphere defined as above is closed under the usual topology on Euclidean space, but there are topologies on Euclidean space, for example the [indiscrete topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_topology) in which the sphere would not be a closed set.

Comment: @RobArthan: sure, but it's completely irrelevant, as the question doesn't talk about Euclidean space at all. It talks about a metric space $X$ with metric $d$, and defines the sphere in terms of metric $d$, and not in terms of the square root of sum of squares of differences of coordinates.

Comment: @xyxxyz: good for you! I see that you did not need my attempt to help you defend yourself against SphericalTriangle's unconstructive criticisms! Actually the question is rather vague about what $d$ is, but your reading is the sensible one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $y$ in the complement of your sphere, $S(x_0, r)^c$.

If $y$ is inside the sphere, meaning $d(x_0, y) < r$, then consider $\varepsilon = r - d(x_0, y) > 0$ and the open ball $B(y, \varepsilon)$.

For $z \in B(y, \varepsilon)$ we have

$$d(x_0, z) \le d(x_0, y) + d(y,z) < d(x_0, y) + r - d(x_0, y) = r $$

Hence $B(y, \varepsilon) \subseteq S(x_0, r)^c$.

If $y$ is on the outside of the sphere, meaning $d(x_0, y) > r$, then consider $\varepsilon = d(x_0, y) -r > 0$ and the open ball $B(y, \varepsilon)$.

For $z \in B(y, \varepsilon)$ we have

$$d(x_0, y) \le d(x_0, z) + d(y,z) \implies d(x_0, z) \ge d(x_0, y) - d(y,z) > d(x_0, y)- d(x_0, r) +r= r $$

Hence $B(y, \varepsilon) \subseteq S(x_0, r)^c$.

$\therefore$ in any case we have, for all $y\in S(x_0,r)^c$, there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that $B(x_0,\varepsilon)\subseteq S(x_0,r)^c$.

So, $S(x_0, r)^c$ is open which implies that $S(x_0, r)$ is closed.

Comment: Why $d(x_0,y)-d(x_0,r)+r=r$?

Comment: @Roma_Rayado It is a typo, $d(x_0,r)$ should be $d(x_0,y)$. Thanks for bringing it up.

Answer (score 6):

Easiest way to prove this is to first prove that the function $d_{x_0}: X \to \mathbb{R}$, defined as $d_{x_0} = d(x, x_0)$, is continuous (this follows essentially from the triangle inequality for the metric $d$), and then to note that the preimage of a closed set under a continuous function is closed, a singleton set $\{r\}$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$, and $S(x_0, r) = d_{x_0}^{-1}(\{r\})$.

Comment: If I $X$ has the indiscrete topology and $X$ has more than $1$ point, you are not going to be able to prove any continuity.

Comment: @sphericalTriangle I think $X$ is supposed to be a metric space, otherwise it wouldn't make any sense to consider a distance.

Comment: @Javi You can have a metric space and still need to work with another topology.

Comment: @sphericalTriangle that's so unnatural that it should be specified.

Comment: @SphericalTriangle: it is absolutely clear what the problem is asking to prove, and what the topology here is. There's no need to mention that the topology is induced by metric every time this is the case, especially as the context doesn't give any alternative topology to be considered. There's no need to be rude either, which you are right now.

Comment: @Javi That is so common that the specific context I have in mind appears in every basic course in functional analysis.