# Prove $f: X \to \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ where $f(x) = d(x, x_o)$ is a continuous function

Tags: solution-verification, continuity, metric-spaces, epsilon-delta, triangle-inequality

I've read here: [Proving that a sphere is a closed set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2702520/proving-that-a-sphere-is-a-closed-set) that the function  $f: X \to \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ where $f(x) = d(x, x_o)$ is a continuous function and that it can be proven continuous via the triangle inequality. Before I attempt this proof, the answer in the link provided mentioned it's a map from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$ , but would it be better to say that it's a map from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ due to distance function's outputs being non-negative?

Let $X$  be a metric space. If $x, x_o \in X$, consider the function $f(x) = d(x, x_o)$ which defines the map $f: X \to \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$.

$f$ is continuous at some $x \in X$ if $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0 : d(x, y) < \delta \Rightarrow d(f(x), f(y)) < \epsilon$ where $y \in X$

suppose we have some $x, y \in X$, some $\epsilon$, and let's choose $\delta = \epsilon$

$d(x, y) < \delta$

$\Rightarrow d(x, y) < \epsilon\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:(1)$

Consider a third element $x_o \in X$

From the triangle inequality, we have ...

$d(y, x_o) \leq d(x, x_o) + d(x, y)$

$\Rightarrow d(y, x_o) - d(x, x_o) \leq d(x, y)\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:(2)$

From $(1)$ and $(2)$, we have...

$d(y, x_o) - d(x, x_o) \leq d(x, y) < \epsilon$

$\Rightarrow d(y, x_o) - d(x, x_o)  < \epsilon$

we can now substitute in the function

$\Rightarrow f(y) - f(x)  < \epsilon$

From the triangle inequality, we also have ...

$d(x, x_o) \leq d(y, x_o) + d(x, y)$

$\Rightarrow d(x, x_o) - d(y, x_o) \leq d(x, y)\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:(3)$

From $(1)$ and $(3)$, we have...

$d(x, x_o) - d(y, x_o) \leq d(x, y) < \epsilon$

$\Rightarrow d(x, x_o) - d(y, x_o) < \epsilon$

we can now substitute in the function

$\Rightarrow f(x) - f(y)  < \epsilon$

$f(y) - f(x)$ and $f(x) - f(y)$ are both less than $\epsilon$

$\Rightarrow |f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$

$\Rightarrow d(f(x), f(y)) < \epsilon$

$\Rightarrow$ for any $\epsilon$, we can always find some $\delta$ equal to $\epsilon$ which implies the $\epsilon - \delta$ definition of continuity at any point of $X$

$\Rightarrow f$ is continuous

Comment: Two initial comments. First, when you have a map $f : X \to Y$, the image of $f$ is not necessarily $Y$. It can be a subset of $Y$. Second,I would suggest that you update your proof to highlight the steps and what you’re doing. Currently, it is hard to read, and being quite lazy, I didn’t read the details.

Comment: You're in a metric space rather than a general topological space, so you should take advantage of this by recalling the definition of continuity of functions on metric spaces. Then, can you show that $f(x) - f(y) \leq d(x, y)$? And if you can show this, can you conclude continuity?

Comment: @DamianPavlyshyn I believe you're speaking of the $\epsilon - \delta$ definition.  I've re-attempted the proof. In my attempt, I did show that $f(x) - f(y) \leq d(x, y)$, but I ultimately did this in order to show $d(f(x), f(y)) < \epsilon$. Would you also need to show $f(y) - f(x) \leq d(x, y)$ in order to show $d(f(x), f(y)) < \epsilon$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Damian Pavlyshyn suggested, the function $f(x)= d(x,x_0)$ is not only continuous but also satisfies the Lipschitz condition with constant $1.$ Indeed by triangle inequality we have
$$d(x,x_0)\le d(x,y)+d(y,x_0)$$ Therefore $$f(x)-f(y)=d(x,x_0)-d(y,x_0)\le d(x,y)$$ Switching $x\leftrightarrow y$ gives
$$f(y)-f(x)\le d(y,x)=d(x,y)$$
Hence $$|f(x)-f(y)|\le d(x,y)$$ If one still insists on $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ proof then take $\delta=\varepsilon.$

Answer (score 0):

it is simpler to use sequences.
let ${x_n}$ be sequence in a metric space $X$.
And $x_n\rightarrow x$.
Then, we need to show that $d(x_n,x)\rightarrow 0$.
$(\forall \epsilon)(\exists N)(n>N\rightarrow d(x_n,x)<\epsilon)$ and $n, N$ are natural numbers.
but this is exactly the definition of a convergent sequence:
every ball $B_\epsilon(x)$ contains all but a finite number of points of the sequence.
Take $N>1/\epsilon$ and this completes the proof.

Comment: The OP needs  $x_n\to x$ implies $d(x_n,x_0)\to d(x,x_0).$